# optimizing index on INT column

Tags: mysql

I have an INT column in a mysql table that holds the unix timestamp of when a post was deleted.

So, a value of 0 would mean that a post hasn't been deleted, while 1496002047 would specify time of deletion.

An index on the INT column would take up 4 bytes per row.

To minimize index size, is possible to create an index that would only store the 1st digit or the value? e.g. 0 or 1 and thus only take up 1 byte per row?

Comment: How many records do you have?

Comment: some tables will have tens of millions of rows - also, this particular INT column will be part of multi-column index, so I'm just looking at ways to minimize the index size relative to the table size

Comment: If you're using this field for true / false then you shouldn't index it at all. Boolean indexes make no sense, they waste space and deteriorate performance. Now, you probably think to yourself that I'm spouting nonsense - but I'm not. Index on such field would make sense when you perform range comparisons (deleted between X and Y or similar), but for queries that are checking for 0 or non-zero  - nope, index will make it slower.

Comment: The field holds a unix timestamp of when the post was deleted. So I'd run a query such as SELECT post FROM table WHERE user_id = x AND deleted = 0 ORDER BY post_time

Comment: You also wrote that you want to make it 1 byte per row - that means you have a fixed length of different values which equal 256, including zero. That means, as your data set grows larger, this index becomes less and less selective and thus less and less useful. Again, you don't have to take my word for it, nor the logic that comes with my comment, but the nice thing about IT field is that you can always assert whether someone is right or wrong. Inflate your database and measure. Note - query that you posted above would have no use from index on `deleted` column.

Comment: @Rado were you thinking of building a composite index on user_id and deleted?

Comment: @zedfoxus - yes, I was considering a composite index on user_id, deleted, post_time to get the user's undeleted posts ordered chronologically.

Comment: @Rado go ahead and create an index on user_id + deleted. Ignore post_time from the index. Then run `explain select * from table where user_id = x and deleted = 0 order by post_time` and see if your user_id + deleted composite index is hit. If it is hit, remove the `explain` and just run the select. Let me know if the query executes fast enough for you. If it is, you won't have to massage your indexes any further.